# Can we pass query string from API side using .net core 2.2 version to COSMOSDB?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating web API with .net core 2.2 and cosmosdb(SQL API). But i got stuck here. I have created one register API after that fetching data using email and password. But here the problem is i can't fetch that particular data using email and password, but i can fetch it with that "id". So , this have any solution?

```
var query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Email = k@gmail.com"; (Here i have passed static email)

if (Email != "") { 
    query += $" WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Email, {{ \"Email\": \"{Email}\" }}, true)"; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you share the code you're using?

Comment: I have write query string like this. var query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Email = k@gmail.com"; //var query = $"SELECT * FROM o"; if (Email != "") { query += $" WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Email, {{ \"Email\": \"{Email}\" }}, true)"; }

Comment: @EmailNotification Would be helpful if you editted your question with this information instead of leaving it in the comments.

Comment: Hi @EmailNotification, if you are using DocumentClient to query records then you can use code like below

<code>
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("databaseId", "collectionId");
    var documentClient = new DocumentClient(serviceEndpoint, masterKey);

    var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionUri, "select * from c").AsDocumentQuery();
    var results = new List<Student>();

    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Student>());
    }
</code>